# Extracting a zip file via VBScript running as a service

Tags: windows-7, zip, uac, vbscript

Details

- OS: Windows 7
- UAC: Disabled
- What: I am running a VBScript that extracts a zip file, and the vbscript is kicked off by Jenkins service. I need to use the VBScript, and I can not use external tools that do not exist in a clean windows installation.
- Problem: If the service is running as NT Authority\SYSTEM OR as a local administrator, I get  an error message on screen related to the vbscript unzipping. Running the script as the current user produces no problems at all. Error message is titled: Interactive Services Detection. Dialog text says **A program running on this computer is trying to display a message**. [image: First Dialog that appears]

If you click "view the message" you get a very old looking dialog titled: **Folder Access Denied** with the text **You'll need to provide administrator permission to copy this folder**. [image: Second Dialog that appears]

It seems like it would somehow UAC related, except UAC is supposedly disabled.

- Script:

```
Const noProgressYesAll = &H14
```

Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

zipFile = "C:\test.zip"
unzipPath = "C:\test\"
WScript.Echo "ZIPEXTRACTDIR: " & unzipPath 
WScript.Echo "ZIPFILE: " & zipFile

If objFSO.FileExists(zipFile) Then
    If objFSO.FolderExists(unzipPath) Then
        Set objShell = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )
        Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(zipFile)
        If objSource is Nothing Then
            printMsg "Invalid Zip File " & zipFile
        Else
            unzipLog = zipFile&".log"
            printMsg "Logging to " & unzipLog
            Set objLog = objFSO.OpenTextFile(unzipLog,fsoForWriting,True)
            Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(unzipPath)
            objTarget.CopyHere objSource.Items, noProgressYesAll
            For Each item in objSource.Items
                printMsg "Extracted: " & unzipPath&item.Name
                        objLog.Write unzipPath&item.Name & vbCrLf
                        If objFSO.FileExists(unzipPath&item.Name) Then
                    printMsg "Verified File: " & unzipPath&item.Name
                Else
                    If objFSO.FolderExists(unzipPath&item.Name) Then
                        printMsg "Verified Folder: " & unzipPath&item.Name
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            objLog.Close
        End If
    Else
        printMsg "Directory does not exist: " & unzipPath
    End If
Else
    printMsg "Zip file does not exist: " & zipFile
End If
Set objLog = Nothing
Set objSource = Nothing
set objShell = Nothing
set objTarget = Nothing

Comment: You have a fair few WScript.Echo's in there which would try and display a pop-up window.

Comment: I suppose I should have added: it is being run w/ cscript, so all output is put into the command window, not as a popup.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the `WScript.Echo` and the `printMsg` (which appears to have no corresponding `Sub` so will fail with an error if it gets called) and then running it with `wscript`? That would prevent a command window appearing - which may be what is triggering that pop-up.

Comment: Yes. I forgot to include the printMsg routine, which for this instance is a WScript.Echo.

Comment: @Richard However is not causing this issue at all; the error clearly shows that it is a permissions problem with the `objTarget.CopyHere` call.